# Lack of anti-aliasing leads to question being closed without chance to improve it

Tags: support, closed-questions, specific-question

My question [Turn off anti-aliasing in Photoshop](https://superuser.com/questions/426046/how-to-draw-1-pixel-line-without-anti-aliasing) was closed because people do not know what anti-aliasing is. I had no time to improve it. The same user who demonstrated lack of knowledge closed the question in 9 minutes.

From my point of view, the question was well defined even in its initial form and absolutely OK now when I added the anti-aliasing illustration.

Is it possible to:

1. Reopen the question to allow people to answer it?
2. Change the posting algorithm so that questions can live longer before being closed?
3. Contact the users who closed my question about their decision?

Comment: You can go improve it now, and then people might reopen it.

Comment: Closure is not an end state. Go and improve it and flag it for moderator review.

Comment: @murgatrid99 how people can reopen question if it is closed? if it still visible when closed? then what closure means?

Comment: As your first point notes, closure means that it cannot be answered. As far as I know, that is the only relevant effect here. And anyone who can close a question can also reopen one.

Comment: But is the closed question still visible in the stream? I.e. can people comment on it or vote on it?

Comment: @SuzanCioc That's right: closing does not affect where a question is displayed; and voting, closing and editing are all still possible. (Questions hidden from the home page if they're voted down to -4, and hidden everywhere on the site if they're deleted.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1) reopen the question for people can answer it?

To get your question reopened, you'll need to convince five people with at least 3000 reps (or one moderator) that your question is worth opening. See: [How do you reopen a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question)

Posting here on meta is one way to drive attention to your question but is a double-edge sword as it may instead result in downvotes. Make sure you address any ambiguity or issues with the question before driving in the herd.

> 2) change stackoverflow algorithm so that questions can live more time before closed?

Closure of questions is not powered by some faceless algorithm -- it is a result of higher rep users actually reading your question and concluding that it does not currently meet the guidelines of the site. See: [What is a "closed" or “on hold” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question)

Hence, there is no algorithm to change -- only the community's perception of what is a valid question, as well as your own approach to asking question.

> 3) Lower @runtime reputation from my point of view or in some other way set that I am absolutely disagree with his/her comments and decisions?

It is not possible or sensible to reduce someone's reputation just because you disagree with their decision.

You can voice your disagreement by posting a comment on the question or here on meta, but at the end of the day (just as in real life) the community's judgment outweighs the individual's, and elected individuals (e.g. moderators) are entrusted with the authority to enforce the norms.

Yes, sometimes questions do get closed wrongly due to some ambiguity or lack of information. That is why there's a procedure for getting it reopen and ways for users to get it reviewed (by posting on meta, or [flagging for moderator attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24560/flagging-a-post-for-moderator-review)).

Comment: How can I dispute question closure if it is ok from my point of view? What if people are wrong about it even if they are in many?

Comment: How to dispute? By posting here on meta which is what you've done. If enough people agree with you, you'll get enough re-open votes.

Comment: You did dispute the closure by asking this question here. If enough people agree with you that the question should be reopened, then they will reopen it.

Comment: But I see no discussion on the question topic. Nobody say why my question is bad or good.

Comment: @Shawn but the time protection may be introduced for somebody be unable to judge very fast. Suppose my question looks bad for moderator because moderator does not know something, but other people can judge it good or upvote. If time pass and some upvotes appear, moderator could think question was good despite his impression.

Comment: Time protection will only hinder the ability of moderators and high-rep users to address issues with submitted content. You'll be surprised at how much moderation is required. Yes, occasionally things to get closed wrongly, but that's why the system of re-open votes exist.

Answer (score 2):

The question was closed based on quality and no signs of prior attempt. It was not an issue of what anti-aliasing means.

Questions that leave much to openness and stabbing:

- Were you using a pencil set at 1 pixel that was still showing this feathering?
- Are you using a brush?
- Was the line straight up and down or some other tilt?
- Was it using the Bézier curve line?
- Are you using a custom shape tool?
- What have you tried to change in your Photoshop setup?

The edit needed to mention at least a method you were trying in the first instance.

When questions are closed due to quality or lack of detail, an edit to include such information will increase its chances of being reopened.

Comment: You could ask for any additional details it the question you closed. Now you did even worth thing: you have edited the question so that it looks duplicate and closed it anyway. I guess this is very impolite.

Comment: The very first comment left on the question was asking to add details into the question. The only edits that followed were screenshots about what anti-aliasing is and not about what you've already tried.

Comment: I have already found EXACT answer on my EXACT initial question. So what to do now? I can edit my question back to it's initial form and then, if you allow the question to exist, I will post this answer. What do you say?